# How to reshape an array one dimension to multiple

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array which has the shape

```
>>> x.shape
>>> (10,)
>>> x.shape[0]
>>> (20,20,3)
```

I want to transform `x into : (10,20,20,3)`.

Comment: np.array(x).reshape(-1,20,20,3) does not work, it says" cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (20.20.3)

Comment: What? How is that possible, can you share your array via code?

Comment: "*`x.shape[0]` is `(20,20,3)`*", can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: If `x.shape` is (10,), then `x.shape[0]` is 10, not (20, 20, 3).

Comment: The dtype of `x` must be `object`.  If all element arrays are the same shape, then `np.stack(x)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

YXes, np.stack did work. Thank you @hpaulj